# Auto refresh ajax content

Tags: javascript, ajax, iframe, refresh

I'm currently trying to design a webpage with some semi-dynamic content but I am unsure as to how to proceed.

My webpage is going to be static for most of the year, but on certain days of the year, I'd like to do a small feature with images and text that refresh in some arbitary period. I don't want to refresh the whole page, just the image/text portion. And because its on certain days of the year (which I will check with php) I don't want to have a refresh (javascript or whatever) working all year around anyway.

My original plan was to put the image/text in an iframe and have the refresh specific to that frame but then I realised that the amount of text is going to be variable and may overrun the frame, giving it scrollbars which I don't want.

So my current idea is to have the image/text content refresh via Ajax but only that part and not the whole page. But I am not sure how to do this or whether there are any better suggestions?

Comment: Instead of polling at regular interval, it would be good to implement a push model. Check [firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) and [socket.io](http://socket.io/) examples.

Comment: socket.io looks interesting, but it seems that I need shell access to install it? - which I don't have :(

Answer (score 0):

```
  setTimeout(function(){
//Portion that you want to Refresh
},Time); /
```

or

```
setInterval(function(){
    //Portion that you want to Refresh
    },Time);
```